# How do you find the positive integer solutions of this equation with the conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Compute the number of positive integers solutions of the following equation:

$x_{1}+2x_{2}+3x_{3}+10x_{4}+2x_{5}=n,$

where $x_{1}\le 4$, and $3\le x_{2}\le 7$.

I am using the generating functions approach and have come up with

$\frac{1-x^5}{1-x} \times\frac{1-x^8}{1-x^4}\times\frac{1}{1-x^3}\times\frac{1}{1-x^10}\times\frac{1}{1-x^2}$

Given the boundaries I am unsure if the generating functions for $x_{1} and$ $ 2x_{2}$are correct

Comment: If $n$ is not limited/fixed, you can find an infinite amount of solutions.

Comment: @ThomasLang I think OP is asking for the solution count as a function of $n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should show us that you've made an effort! Otherwise, the question will likely be closed, since MSE is not meant to be a site where others solve your problems for you!

Answer (score 0):

You have not formulated properly the product.

The product defining the OGF of the number of **positive** integral solutions is
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {z^{\,1}  + z^{\,2}  + z^{\,3}  + z^{\,4} } \right)\left( {\left( {z^{\,2} } \right)^{\,3}  +  \cdots
  + \left( {z^{\,2} } \right)^{\,7} } \right)\left( {\left( {z^{\,3} } \right)^{\,1}  + \left( {z^{\,3} } \right)^{\,2}  +  \cdots } \right) \cdot   \cr 
  &  \cdot \left( {\left( {z^{\,10} } \right)^{\,1}  + \left( {z^{\,10} } \right)^{\,2}  +  \cdots } \right)\left( {\left( {z^{\,2} } \right)^{\,1}
  + \left( {z^{\,2} } \right)^{\,2}  +  \cdots } \right) \cr} 
$$
If you try to expand it, you will see that the construction of the coefficient of $z^n$ obeys to the given system.

hint: start with a small example, to understand how to fit the coefficients of the linear combination plus the boundaries